# Fatal Exception Main running Application on Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, execution

I have been programming an app, and at the time I want to do the testing, the eclipse Logcat gives me the following log I dont know why this is happening, the phone and the emulator give the "Unfortunately you application has stopped" message:

```
07-26 19:47:03.880: W/dalvikvm(834): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.xanmaya.kapschfinal/com.xanmaya.kapschfinal.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at com.xanmaya.kapschfinal.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:36)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  ... 11 more
```

Here is the code:

```
 package com.xanmaya.kapschfinal;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


Button btnEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    }}
);
return true;

}
EditText etModulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etModulo);
EditText etAmpli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmpli);
EditText etAntena = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAntena);
EditText etCable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCable);
EditText etFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFecha);
EditText etlugar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlugar);
EditText etenvia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etenvia);
CheckBox checkampli = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkampli);
CheckBox checkantena = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkantena);
CheckBox checkmodulo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulo);
CheckBox checkcable = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkcable);

{
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "villasantdesign@gmail.com");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Resumen");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etModulo.getText()); etAntena.getText(); etCable.getText(); etlugar.getText(); etFecha.getText(); etAmpli.getText();}{;
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "btnEnviar"));}}`code:
```

Ill appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, does this code even compile? or you just pasted it here wrong?

1)your findViews should go in the onCreate after your setContentView().

So add this in your onCreate

```
EditText etModulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etModulo);
EditText etAmpli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmpli);
EditText etAntena = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAntena);
EditText etCable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCable);
EditText etFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFecha);
EditText etlugar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlugar);
EditText etenvia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etenvia);
CheckBox checkampli = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkampli);
CheckBox checkantena = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkantena);
CheckBox checkmodulo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulo);
CheckBox checkcable = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkcable);
```

2) Moreover what is this code in the middle of nowhere doing?

```
{
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "villasantdesign@gmail.com");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Resumen");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, etModulo.getText()); etAntena.getText(); etCable.getText(); etlugar.getText(); etFecha.getText(); etAmpli.getText();}{;
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "btnEnviar"));}}:
```

Add this inside the onClick of your btnEnviar.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, call all your view initializations in `onCreate` after call to setContentView. Class members initializations are called in constructor right after call to implicit or not `super (...)`. Your view is created later in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

The lines from the log to focus on are

```
    07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
    07-26 19:47:03.910: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at com.xanmaya.kapschfinal.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:36)
```

findViewById() is not finding a view with the specified View at line 36 of MainActivity.  Check that this view exists in your xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to read your code the way it is formatted but it appears that these lines

```
EditText etModulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etModulo);
EditText etAmpli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmpli);
EditText etAntena = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAntena);
EditText etCable = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCable);
EditText etFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFecha);
EditText etlugar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlugar);
EditText etenvia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etenvia);
CheckBox checkampli = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkampli);
CheckBox checkantena = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkantena);
CheckBox checkmodulo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulo);
CheckBox checkcable = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkcable);
```

are outside of any method so they would get called before anything else, particularly `onCreate()` where you call `setContentView()` which would make them `null`.

Your `Views` exist in your layout so they will return `null` if you try to initialize them before inflating your layout by calling `setContentView()`. A more conventional way, and more readable way would be to declare them as member variables then initialize them in `onCreate()` or in an initialization method if you choose AFTER the all to `setContentView()`. So it may look something like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText etModulo;   // you can declare them as member variables here so they can be used anywhere in the class
    EditText etAmpli; 
    EditText etAntena; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etModulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etModulo);   // but initialize them here after inflating your layout
    etAmpli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAmpli);
    etAntena = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAntena);

}
```